# UPDATE part of value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, sql-update

I would like to update the part of the field.

For example, I would like to change from

```
aacity,bbcity,cccity,ddcity
```

to

```
aatown,bbtown,cctown,ddtown.
```

Is there a way to achieve this in one query?

Comment: It would more specifically on your dataset e.g. whether it's always 6 characters long and you just need to replace the last 4 characters? I would look at using SUBSTR in and UPDATE query.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma delimited values in a single column in the first place. You should really fix your data model first

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.what i mean is i have three record in my table aatown,bbtown,cctown then i would like to change to aacity,bbcity,cccity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SQL FIDDLE`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2aee2)

```
UPDATE test
SET col = regexp_replace(col, '(?:city)','town','g');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** use expensive regular expressions for a static replacement. Use the simple and cheap [**`replace()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html). Replaces *all* occurrences of the substring in the string.

Also, **don't** run the `UPDATE` unconditionally. This will write a new row version of each and every row, even if nothing changes. Expensive nonsense.

Use instead:

```
UPDATE test
SET    col = replace(col, 'city', 'town')
WHERE  col <> replace(col, 'city', 'town');  -- only where necessary
```